# AngularDart template not found

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When working on my project in AngularDart, I created a component called LoginComponent:

```dart
// lib/component/login.dart
@Component(
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html')
class LoginComponent {
    String username;
    String password;
}
```

In the same folder where I created the login.dart script, I also put it's template code:

```html
<!-- /lib/component/login.html -->
<form ng-submit="login()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The project's structure looks as follows:

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── lib
│   ├── annotations.dart
│   └── component
│       ├── login.dart
│       └── login.html
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
└── web
    ├── index.html
    └── main.dart
```

I also added the html template to the angular transformer:

```yaml
name: 'duseapp'
version: 0.0.1
description:
  An absolute bare-bones web app.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  browser: any
  web_components: ">=0.10.1 <0.11.0"
  angular: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"
  restpoint:
    git: git://github.com/Adracus/restpoint.git
  duse:
    git: git://github.com/duse-io/duse-dart.git
transformers:
  - angular:
    html_files:
      - lib/component/login.html
```

But now, I'm receiving the error:

```
Target of URI does not exist: 'login.html'
```

Does anybody know what's the cause of this?
For further insight, the github url of the project is [here](https://github.com/duse-io/duseapp).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for a day, I found an [interesting post on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular-dart/VQMbC5Qz1Ls/azck7GKyUEAJ), which solved my problem (except for a little mistake, it is 'packages' instead of 'package'). According to the post, one should specify the `templateUrl` as follows:

```
templateUrl: 'packages/<package-name>/<any-lib-subdirectory>/<filename>'
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: According to issues and wiki page in the Angular.dart repo relative paths should work since several months.

Comment: It's a warning during the build process and the Dart Editor marks the corresponding line, but it works though